# Access messages in express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

How can I access messages in express-validator generated from the .withMessage() method? My aim is to render the error message using res.render where {messages = ???}. The function itself is working fine.

Here is my validator function

```
const userValidationRules = () => {
  return [

    //Whole Body Validation

    body('username').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('username must be at least 5 chars long'), //{"errors":[{"username":"username must be at least 5 chars long"}]}

    body('password').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('password must be at least 5 chars long'),
  ]
}

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next()
  }

  const extractedErrors = []
  errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }))

   console.log("extractedErrors = "+ extractedErrors )

    // return res.render("index", {    
    //       messages :  //display error messages here
    //   });

  return res.status(422).json({  
    errors: extractedErrors,

  })



}
```

a short username outputs {"errors":[{"username":"username must be at least 5 chars long"}]}

I am using the console.log() to find the message value - "username must be at least 5 chars long".

console.log("extractedErrors = "+ extractedErrors ) logs 'extractedErrors= [object Object]'
so how can I access this object?

console.log("extractedErrors = "+ extractedErrors["errors"] ) logs 'extractedErrors= undefined'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, every structured javascript error has logic in it.they separate error message error code... Try to use this code:

```
 console.log(extractedErrors["errors"].message)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this throws an error message - TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Comment: Are you logging a single error? Another subjection not related to this question is use something called koi nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I ended up remapping the returned error into a more accessible object:

```
errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push( err.msg ));
```

I could then use extractedErrors[0] to get at the message.